# Are there any arguments against LED strings for crawlspace lighting?

Tags: lighting, basement, crawlspace

I have a small unfinished basement (1929 house) into which I regularly venture down (HVAC, electrical panel, IT, some food storage). The basement is surrounded by a (dirt) crawlspace and every time I get the chance, I look around for issues and anomalies. However, I am really frustrated by the darkness and grabbing a strong light every time and moving around is annoying. Also, often paths for the light rays are obstructed by duct work and beams.

I got two simple ceramic lamp holders and put on 6000 lumens LED lamps. While the light itself is good, I would need way more of them to reach behind duct work and beams.

From electrical perspective, I know GFCI is a requirement but bare bulbs themselves are allowed. My breaker for basement/crawlspace is GFCI+AFCI.

Now I got the idea to just use string lights. They are up to 24ft and can be extended (nearly) arbitrarily long. I could just add a simple switched receptacle and run the string light across the entire perimeter, just hanging with nails.

Sounds efficient, easy, cheap. Are there any possible issues to consider?

I am not sure about using an [LED string](https://www.harborfreight.com/24-ft-12-bulb-shatterproof-outdoor-led-string-lights-black-56869.html) or [incandescent string](https://www.harborfreight.com/24-ft-12-bulb-outdoor-incandescent-string-lights-black-63483.html). I would be leaning towards the LED version because it's more efficient and I believe more robust (hoping I do not have to venture into the crawl space often to replace bulbs).

Are there any arguments against LED strings?

Comment: As you've explicitely asked about string lights, I'm not putting this as an answer, but have you considered a head torch left down there? It possibly wouldn't light up the far reaches as well as well placed string lights, but would be *much* easier to fit! Head torches are the best.

Comment: I'm 100% in support of the head lamp suggestion. I've spent a _huge_ amount of time in my crawl space in the last 18 months doing plumbing & electrical for some new construction. The light is _always_ with you and always aimed exactly where you need it, it's never shining in your eyes and you never have to take your hands off what you're working on to hold/aim it. I always have my phone as an emergency backup flashlight and a spare set of batteries, just in case. Plus a plug in lamp near the crawl space entrance, just in case.

Comment: I'd suggest some strings of LEDs for general low lighting, and a nice bright headlamp. My personal favorite is the Lightbar (no affiliation) that throws a lot of light over a broad angle. More focused beams and my progressive lenses don't get along well because the beam and the part of the lens I need to use at a given distance never seem to coincide... Anyway, you may still be able to get outdoor rated white LED strings on sale after Christmas. Just don't set them to twinkle mode.

Comment: Yes, look for outdoor-rated strings at minimum. Consider *waterproof* strings; they're easy to find on e.g. Amazon.

Comment: Let me clarify again that per my post I am NOT primarily looking for a light when I am working in the crawlspace. As I wrote, I want to light so I can easily scan the crawlspace for anomalies when standing outside in the basement. Hence the headlamp is not the right solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

##### TL;DR LED

Other than nostalgia - which sometimes has something going for it, but not for functional lighting in a crawlspace - there are really only 4 reasons for incandescent lighting instead of LED lighting:

- The original Easy Bake Oven, and some similar things that used a light bulb as a heating element
- Technical issues, typically where a single incandescent bulb in a fixture will prevent LEDs from blinking or having other problems
- Where you actually want the heat to help keep an area warm and/or dry - which is not terribly efficient but *sometimes* can make sense.
- Inside ovens - LEDs don't like that much heat.

The example string lights you linked don't list lumens. But Googling replacement bulbs, I found pretty much what I expected:

- Incandescent = 11W per bulb, 40 lumens per bulb
- LED = 1W per bulb, 50 lumens per bulb

In other words, the LED lights will provide about the same amount of light - maybe more - as the incandescent lights while using 1/10 (or less) of the electricity. YMMV, depending on quality of bulb.

Plus the LED bulbs will generally last much longer than equivalent incandescent bulbs, which is a bonus considering the hassle of replacing bulbs in a crawlspace.

Comment: …and with the introduction of LED filament lamps that look a lot like fancy old-style incandescents, even the nostalgia factor may lean on the LED side nowadays :)

Comment: LED's are are also far more impact resistant than incandescent bulbs, even if the glass of an incandescent does not break, disturbing the (hot) filament is often fatal for the lamp.

Comment: Some years ago we had a really bad cold snap, record lows, people's pipes bursting. Local hardware stores were all out of heat tape. Still had plenty of trouble lights (bulb on the end of an extension cord with a hook to hang it). Hanging one with a 100W bulb onto the hose bibs and putting a cardboard box over it kept mine from freezing. So using a bulb to heat occasionally really does work...

Comment: But, LED light color is generally horrible and the flicker can cause headaches. Not all the sunshine and roses you read about LEDs is completely true...

Comment: Color, cri and flicker all depend on quality of the bulb.

Comment: @FreeMan: Like manassehkatz says, it depends on the bulb. A good rule of thumb is to never buy the cheapest ones, at least not without checking a review first. (Here's [a nice LED bulb review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeR2uPPCA2k) I just randomly found on YouTube recently. Maybe surprisingly, some of the bulbs tested actually had _less_ flicker and/or a better CRI than incandescents.)

Comment: Funny, @IlmariKaronen, I just watched his review of LED light strips yesterday. Hadn't seen the bulb review. My point is simply that marketing makes everything sound wonderful and glosses over (sometimes major) flaws. One has to apply thought and common sense and realize that every new thing isn't inherently better than the old thing _just because_ it's new.

Comment: @FreeMan: True enough… and yet, nowadays LEDs really are leaving all the other currently available lighting technologies in the dust. Yes, there are crappy LED bulbs on the market, but compared to good (or even just mediocre) modern LED bulbs, basically _all_ fluorescent and incandescent lights are crap. Incandescents still have some niche applications (like oven lights, or photography / photometry uses requiring a near-perfect black body spectrum) but outside those there's no reason not to choose LEDs these days. Unless you need a compact electric heater with an integrated light, I guess.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The one key difference is quality problems. With incandescent, the cheap bulbs (as opposed to GE, Philips, etc.) produced identical light quality as a name brand, just were more likely to be DOA or die early. With LEDs, the cheap bulbs often have flicker, CRI, color, etc. problems - *and the average user doesn't know what to look for*. And while rarely DOA, poor quality LEDs are also more likely to die early - the difference is 2,000 vs. 20,000 hours (so typically long after you threw away the receipt) rather than 100 vs. 1,000 hours.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: And using those numbers a low end LED (2000 hour) is still better / less hassle to replace than a high end (1000 hour) incandescent.

Comment: @BenVoigt Agreed. With the caveat that if the low-end LED has serious flicker or color issues then it isn't worth it at any price. But hard to tell much of that when you buy it. Can tell CRI and color *if you know what you are looking for, which I think most people don't*. For that matter, far too many people *still* don't understand that Watts is not a measure of light but of power.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, "better CRI than incandescent" is incredibly suspect. Incandescents are black body radiators. CRI is a measure of how close a light source comes to a comparable black body radiator (which, by definition, has a CRI of 100, i.e. "perfect"). Now, maybe this was comparing some absolutely incredible LED against an incandescent whose CRI had been reduced somehow, but as a general rule, an LED is *at best* as good as an incandescent in terms of CRI.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen,  OTOH, "less flicker" is quite possible. An incandescent on AC "warbles" at 50/60 Hz (it doesn't turn off instantly, so it doesn't go 'completely off' the way an LED with no smoothing — or worse, using only half-bridge rectification — does). An LED with good smoothing capacitance — which is to say, driven by fairly constant DC — will be as steady as the DC input. That said, an incandescent on DC will be at least as smooth, perhaps more so due to the filament's built-in "lag". But of course household bulbs are almost universally run on AC.

Comment: FYI, 50lm/W is sort of terrible these days. The state of the art is more like 133lm/W, or was last I looked (which was already maybe a couple years ago).

Comment: @Matthew: The test measured a CRI of 96.3 for the incandescent bulb and 96.5 for the best LED (and 96.1 for the second best). The spectrum of the LEDs (also shown in the video) is clearly far from a black-body, but the CRI test only measures the colorimetric rendering of a limited sample of test colors, and it seems the spectrum of those LEDs is quite well optimized for it. (I can't really comment on the test methodology, e.g. whether the CRI for the incandescent bulb was measured right. Someone more familiar with the topic could maybe get more detail out of what's shown on the video.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, that sounds plausible. The incandescent is probably losing a bit of CRI due to the surrounding glass or other factors. Those numbers however are close enough (both to each other and to 100) that I'd take the claim of "better" with a grain of salt; more like "equivalent". Though I suspect the LED might fall behind if the test were more comprehensive. I don't dispute however that really good LEDs exist.

Comment: 5. Incandescent has a much better spectrum than LEDs, even good ones.
6. LEDS still have issues with super cold weather, IME (related to your #2)

Answer (score 2):

LEDs are a perfect solution. Current LED strips are waterproof, flexible and easy to install. You can buy outdoor versions typically used for holiday lighting (the white ones).
There's many choices with brightness rivaling any fixture options.
Get a nice long strip or multiple,  and turn that tunnel into a Star Trek Jefferies Tube.

The headlamp idea may be useful, but also cumbersome.  Something you'll need to keep charged, and is one extra step compared to the simplicity of a light switch.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that old Christmas lights work great.  A few light bulbs burned out on our Christmas lights.  My wife wanted to get rid of them.  I hung them up in our crawlspace and it makes a huge difference.  Of course, LED lights would be even better. Good luck with your project.   [image: crawl space lit with old Christmas lights.]

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd run LED tape. It's low profile, generally bright enough for most applications, and relatively plentiful. You can wire them directly into a circuit if need be, or a switched outlet. The advantages of a switched outlet is that it makes the drivers easier to replace if you get a system that has the drivers upstream from the tape.

(Side note: LEDs are far less likely to fail than the drivers that rectify their current. If you can get something where you can replace the drivers as a discrete unit separate from the tape/string, it will make your installation far easier to maintain.)

If the tape doesn't want to stay, you can lay it over some nails with a wide head, something like roofing nails would be perfect, as the cap will be sufficient to hold it. From there, I'd run a row along the side near the bottom of each joist in the area(s) of interest, as well as a second row attached to the actual bottom of the joists, so that you can also see the ground more clearly.

Comment: My experience differs.  I have replace over 40 led units in my house.  It is always the leds that fail, not the drivers.  And no, they are not cheap imported junk.

Answer (score 0):

**Use LED STRIP lights not string lights**.  These are perfect for the stated requirements.  Nice even lighting everywhere, but also importantly they are low voltage, and designed to be stapled (or whatever) to anything, indoors.  They are a lot safer that your proposed solution or Christmas lights.

I wouldn't string up miles of 120V lamp cable mounted to wood in a crawl space, cable that is not designed for hard-to-reach, somewhat concealed, somewhat indoor spaces, but is designed to be hung outdoors, usually temporarily, and not designed to be permanent.   I would worry about the wire or the sockets or the bulbs failing at some point and igniting a fire.  I'd also worry about anyone crawling around down there with tools shattering bulbs that are just dangling from the low ceiling.  Even if they are plastic LED bulbs there is still some danger.

If you need to string up any 120V circuits for anything, use MC cable and metal junction boxes but keep it to a minimum and use low voltage for your lighting.  If that's what you want ... even light everywhere in a tight space ... it's perfect.  Given the hard-to-reach aspect of this, I suggest you buy high quality name brand stuff for reliability.

Answer (score -2):

Since you're just scanning the area, you might want to consider installing a few floodlight cameras. They're so cheap now it really wouldn't cost that much. You'd be able to check more often and from a recliner.

Comment: The "look around for issues/anomalies" is _secondary_ to doing whatever "HVAC, electrical, IT, food storage" the OP needs to do as the _primary_ reason for going down there. Unless there's some home automation hardware I'm not aware of, getting food out of storage or resetting a tripped breaker via camera is going to be... challenging.